# Could STL containers be used without being destroyed if the allocator's deallocate() is noop?

Tags: c++, stl, memory-pool

Sorry for the long title~

I have a simple allocator implemented on top of a memory pool whose `deallocate()` is empty. If a STL container is used with this allocator and the elements of the container are trivially destructible, can I avoid invoke the container's destructor altogether ?

The standard probably says no, I'm not sure though. IMO, if this behavior is allowed, STL containers couldn't get any resources other than memory allocated from their allocators, which would limit STL vendors too much. I'm never an expert on the standard, I'd be glad to be proven wrong.

However, if my simple allocator is used along with some actual implementation like libstdc++ or libc++, would the program leak memory or run into other problems ?

Comment: `deallocate` is about memory, not about objects. Objects are destroyed with `destroy`.

Comment: Since elements are trivially destructible, `destroy` isn't implemented.

Comment: If you have an implementation in which noop `deallocate` plus trivial element destructor isn't optimized away into nothing, you should file a bug with your compiler vendor. So...why do you care?

Comment: @T.C. are you sure about this ? because I have to create & destroy hundreds of thousands of `std::list` and store up to millions of elements into them. I don't want to roll a `my::list` template